# Cannot convert from int to int**

Tags: c

I have written a program which has to calculate all the prime actors from 1 - 20 and store it in a 2D array . But i am not getting why factor is not storing the values ,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime_check(int number, int **p);

int
main(void)
{
    int **factor;

    factor = (int **) malloc(21 * sizeof(int *));
    for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++)
        factor[j] = (int *) malloc(8 * sizeof(int));
    for (int number = 2; number <= 20; number++) {
        prime_check(number, factor);
    }
    printf("%d", factor[4][4]);         /* Main Function Ends */
}

int
prime_check(int number, int **p)
{
    int pos = 0;
    int test = number;

    while (!(number % 2)) {
        p[test][pos] = 2;
        pos++;
        number = number / 2;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
        while (number % i == 0) {
            p[test][pos] = i;
            pos++;
            number = number / i;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your memory allocations are unusual , can you write some comments what you are doing there?

Comment: `factor` is actually storing values, are you sure your algorithm works correctly? You can use two nested loops to print all the values of `factor` and examine them.

Comment: Your algorithm looks to work, why are you saying that `factor` is not getting any values? Why are you specifically printing value `factor[4][4]`, which value are you expecting there?

Comment: i was checking the values that's why , but when I'm printing the values by using a loop garbage values are comming

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you have additional information. You might consider to show your check in source, to let us have a [example]. -- You are not initializing the members of the arrays, and so their initial values are random. -- In C you usually don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program appears to be working.  It does generate duplicate factors.

The following function will dump your results

```
void results(int rows, int cols, int** array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        printf( "%4d - ", i );
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
        {
            printf( "%2d ", array[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

You can call it as

```
results(20, 7, factor)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for assistance , but when I'm printing using a loop garbage values are comming out , that's why I'm confused at the moment , maybe i need to try with some other compiler

Comment: I don't believe malloc is required to clear memory, so you may be seeing the previous memory values. You may need to zero the rows when you allocate them.